# Using Ramda with React to setState

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js

I am trying to use `ramda` for my filtering. I have read the Ramda docs in detail.

However, my attempt to filter it is having no affect on my `setState`, nor the console log.

Live code sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qY219X102

My attempt:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import R from 'ramda';

const o = {
  movies: [
    { name: 'movie 1', genres: ['comedy', 'action'] },
    { name: 'movie 2', genres: ['action', 'drama'] },
    { name: 'movie 3', genres: ['drama', 'action'] },
  ],
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: o,
    };
  }
  getGenre = () => {
    R.pipe(
      R.prop(o.movies),
      R.filter(
        R.and(
          R.propSatisfies(R.find(R.equals('action')), 'genres'),
          R.propSatisfies(R.find(R.equals('comedy')), 'genres'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    this.setState({ o });
    console.log('genre', o);
  };
  render() {
    const rawmovies = Object.keys(o).map(e => o[e]);
    const movies = [].concat.apply([], rawmovies);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getGenre}>Action genre</button>
        {movies.map(e => <span key={e.name}> {e.name}</span>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the actual filtering itself, I find this Ramda snippet much easier to read:

```
filter(both(
  where({genres: contains('drama')}),
  where({genres: contains('action')})    
))
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20o%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20movies%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27movie%201%27%2C%20genres%3A%20%5B%27comedy%27%2C%20%27action%27%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27movie%202%27%2C%20genres%3A%20%5B%27action%27%2C%20%27drama%27%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%27movie%203%27%2C%20genres%3A%20%5B%27drama%27%2C%20%27action%27%5D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getGenre%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27movies%27%29%2C%0A%20%20R.filter%28R.both%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.where%28%7Bgenres%3A%20R.contains%28%27drama%27%29%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.where%28%7Bgenres%3A%20R.contains%28%27action%27%29%7D%29%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0AgetGenre%28o%29)**.  And you can always see the docs for [`filter`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter), [`both`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#both), [`where`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#where), and [`contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains) on the [Ramda site](http://ramdajs.com/).

Comment: Thank you that is much neater. How would I get the "genre" value when it is nested? EG: `genre: [{ name: 'Movie', type: 1 }, { name: 'Adventure', type: 2 }], },` ?

Comment: I might do this: `R.where({genres: R.pipe(R.pluck('name'), R.contains('drama'))}`, or extract that out into a function, so that I could write `R.where({genres: hasType('drama')})`.  This is not the most efficient code imaginable, but I would worry about that only if it caused problems.

Comment: I tried the first option- but no success. I put it in a codepen to show you- https://codesandbox.io/s/DkNzqx7Wn

Comment: `both` won't work with only a single value.  But it didn't work for me when I removed that from your code, nor when I used a list of `where` predicates with `allPass` instead of `both`.  Nonetheless, they work stand-alone, so I think it's something in your React code.  I don't know anything about that, though.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and make some modifications to allow the filtering:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import R from 'ramda';

const o = {
  movies: [
    { name: 'movie 1', genres: ['comedy', 'action'] },
    { name: 'movie 2', genres: ['action', 'drama'] },
    { name: 'movie 3', genres: ['drama', 'action'] },
  ],
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: o.movies,
    };
  }
  getGenre = () => {    
    const filter = R.pipe(
      R.prop('movies'),
      R.filter(
        R.and(
          R.propSatisfies(R.find(R.equals('action')), 'genres'),
          R.propSatisfies(R.find(R.equals('comedy')), 'genres'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    const result = filter(o);        
    this.setState({ movies: result });    
  };
  render() {            
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getGenre}>Action genre</button>
        {this.state.movies.map(e => <span key={e.name}> {e.name}</span>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Sorry if I did not get your question right.

The thing is that Ramda returns a function and your were not storing and using that function for the filtering.

Also in the render method you were not using the movies in the state.